# C#: Populate Listview from XML document

Tags: c#, xml, listview

I want to populate my listview with data from a XML file, which is also generated with this program.

This code only adds the first entry of the XML file. But why?

```
 XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@path + projectName + ".xml");


        var items = from item in document.Descendants("root")


                    select new
                    {
                        Name = item.Element("Child").Attribute("Name").Value,
                        time = item.Element("Child").Attribute("time").Value
                    };


        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var lvi = activitiesList.Items.Add(item.Name);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(item.time);
        }
```

Here is my XML File

```
<root>
 <Child Name="New Activity" time="20" />
 <Child Name="asdf1" time="5" />
 <Child Name="g1" time="0" />
</root>
```

and my Listview should show this in two columns:

```
New Activity  20
asdf1         5
g1            0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the LINQ statement -- you only have one "root" node, so for each "root" node (1), get it's "Child" Element's Name and time and put it in `var items`...

try this one:

```
var items = from item in document.Root.Elements("Child")
            select new
            {
                Name = item.Attribute("Name").Value,
                time = item.Attribute("time").Value
            };
```

Comment: (Some more explanation) The fact that there is only one `root` element is fine, the problem was that you were calling `Element` (singular) on that `root` node, so it would return the first child. Calling `Elements` (plural) solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Check this question and answers out.  This seems to answer your question.  It points to your query not including the "XNamespace" directive.

[Selecting elements from XML file using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14501196/1262984)

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a signpost to the answer.