# Filter result with certain node in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

i have a xml like below

```
<Orders>
<Order>
<ABC>defe</ABC>
</Order>

<Order>
<ABC>asa</ABC>
<YYY>ee1@ee.com</YYY>
</Order>

<Order>
<ABC>tyty</ABC>
<YYY>ee1@ee.com</YYY>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

i want to fetch out the record which have node YYY, like in above case query should return two set of order which contins YYY node in there.First record should be excluded from filtered result.
Result should be

```
<Order>
<ABC>asa</ABC>
<YYY>ee1@ee.com</YYY>
</Order>

<Order>
<ABC>tyty</ABC>
<YYY>ee1@ee.com</YYY>
</Order>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting elements from XML file using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501196/selecting-elements-from-xml-file-using-linq)

Answer (score 1):

See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication116
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> orders = doc.Descendants("Order").Where(x => x.Element("YYY") != null).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh Man this is that simple, i was trying with contains but did not succeed, thanks

Comment: Can you mark his answer as `correct` if it helped you?